# Rescale a nicematrix

Tags: scaling, nicematrix

I have a matrix created with the `nicematrix` package inside of `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}` environment. How can I rescale this matrix?
I tried using `\resizebox`, but didn't succeed.

```
\begin{equation}
T = 
\resizebox{.25\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{pNiceMatrix}[first-row,last-col]
\scriptstyle(000) & \scriptstyle(001) &  \scriptstyle(010) &  \scriptstyle(011) &  \scriptstyle(100) &  \scriptstyle(101) &  \scriptstyle(110) &  \scriptstyle(111) & \\
1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  \scriptstyle(000) \\
1 &  1 &  0 &  1 &  0 &  1 &  0 &  1 &  \scriptstyle(001) \\
1 &  0 &  1 &  1 &  0 &  0 &  1 &  1 &  \scriptstyle(010) \\
1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  1 &  \scriptstyle(011) \\
1 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  \scriptstyle(100) \\
1 &  1 &  0 &  0 &  1 &  1 &  0 &  1 &  \scriptstyle(101) \\
1 &  0 &  1 &  0 &  1 &  0 &  1 &  1 &  \scriptstyle(110) \\
1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  \scriptstyle(111)
\end{pNiceMatrix}%
}
\end{equation}
```

A more generic question: is there a way to rescale anything inside of the `equation` environment, no matter what packages are used inside? Thanks.

Comment: resizing any table should be avoided, it will produce inconsistent font and rule sizes.  In general resizebox is like `\mbox` so its content is text mode and needs a nested `$...$` to get back in to math mode.

Comment: Not related. I suggest you to use `code-for-first-row=\scriptstyle` and `code-for-last-col=\scriptstyle`